# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials - Error while calling an API

Tags: excel, authentication, iis, xmlhttprequest, authorization

I am trying call an API(written in C#) from Excel VBA. The Request message is formed within the Excel VBA and send to the API. The message looks like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<IncomingMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <MessageSource>hello</MessageSource>
   <MessagefromID>Newuser</MessagefromID>
   <MessageVersion>20240221</MessageVersion>
   <MessageType>1</MessageType>
   <Command>Select Count(1) AS count from TableName</Command>
   <MessageParams/>
   <MessageTimeStamp>2024-03-08T14:03:10.00</MessageTimeStamp>
</IncomingMessage>
```

Also some message header are set:

```
httpObject.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/xml"
    httpObject.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(MessageVariable)
```

When I try to call the API from the excel macro I get the error -

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials
```

I would like to have Windows Authentication enabled. Meaning only AD users of the Domain can access the API.

The IIS Authentication setting for the Application Pool is as follows:

```
Anonymous Auth - Disabled
Basic Auth - Disabled
Windows Auth - Enabled
```

The IIS Authorization setting for the Application Pool is as follows:

```
Deny - Anonymous User
Allow - All Users
```

The Identity of the Application pool is "ApplicationPoolIdentity".

Can you please advise, if I should send something extra in the request header to make it work? Or some other IIS settings that must be updated.

Note: I have tried to update the Identity of the Application Pool to "Local System" , but to no use.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 401 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.